# Problem with making vertices into mesh

Tags: mesh, vertices

A Blender novice here.  I'm trying to make a design of a logo for a project that I'm working on for class.  I have the logo designed that is made up of simple vertices. I wanted to make the vertices into solid meshes but I couldn't find the way to do it. I've tried solidifying and skin modifiers but they both deform the design.  Are there any other ways to do this?
Attached is the logo I made in vertices.[image: Picture_Caputre]

Comment: Those look like edges to me, not vertices. Can't you just enter edit mode, select a pair of edges and press `F` to add a facet between them?

Comment: One way is to use Alt-c in object mode to convert it into curve type, then set curve Fill to 'Full' and adjust Bevel Depth.

Comment: I figured it out through the bevel depth, thank you so much kheetor.